# Does anyone know why flutter cannot trigger the onVerticalDragUpdate event after triggering the onLongPress event in GestureDetector

Tags: flutter, gesture, gesturedetector

my code is:

```
GestureDetector(
      child: Text('text'),
      onLongPress: () {
        print('++++++++++++++++++++++++');
      },
      onVerticalDragUpdate: (updateDetails) {
        print('******************************************');
      },
      onHorizontalDragUpdate: (updateDetails){
        print('-----------------------------------');
      },
    ),
```

When I trigger the onLongPress event, the onVerticalDragUpdate event will not be triggered. Why?